# How to debug C++ Runtime Error caused by my DLL?

Tags: runtime-error

I'm writing an addin DLL in C# for a host application written in C++ (I do not have source for the host app).  When I run the host application, it loads my DLL for use during that session.  Recently, I've been seeing the following error upon exit of the host application:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Runtime Error!
Program: MyHostApp.exe

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way...
```

This dialog only contains an "OK" button (no debug button).  After pressing OK, the host app exits without giving any indication of what might have caused the error.

I found this stackoverflow thread with a similar problem...

[How to debug a Visual C++ Runtime Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440355/how-to-debug-a-visual-c-runtime-error)

But, whenever I try to attach VS2008 to the crashed application, and then do a "break all" as instructed, I only get the following message from VS:

"*Unable to break execution.  This process is not currently executing the type of code that you selected to debug.*"

How should I approach debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you trying setting the "Native Code" option when starting the debugger?

Comment: If you mean "Tools | Options | Debugging | Just-In-Time | Native", yes, it's checked.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean...  In the "Attach to Process" dialog, I can select "Native code".  Doing that gets me past the initial message mentioned in the OP.  However, now when I do a "break all", I get a "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame.  The source code cannot be displayed."

I guess that makes sense as I don't have source or symbols for the crashing host app. I'm certain that something in my DLL is causing the host to crash, I just don't know how to find it...

Answer (score 0):

C# does not generate native code! Even if the app is native, C# is executed within nested CLR. Choose "Managed code".

Also, instead of "Break all", set a break on all possible exceptions, then run it to the failure.