# Windows installer built with setup.py bdist_wininst triggers RuntimeError when installing. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, distutils

I'm building an installation EXE for my project using setuptool's bdist_wininst. However, I've found that when I actually run said installer on a Win7-64bit machine w/ Python 2.7.3, I get a Runtime Error that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIWPC.jpg. (only the 64 bit installer against python-2.7 64-bit; the 32-bit one (on python2.7 32-bit) appears fine)  I can click OK and the installer finishes, but this certainly looks poor to end-users.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Just to clairify, Py2.7.3+Win6_64bit doesn't work. Py2.7.4+Win7_32bit works? I assume you're not boundling the runtime libraries correctly.. how do you package your stuff?

Comment: I package with bdist_wininst on ubuntu Linux 12.10 which produces the exe. The distutils code (command/bdist_wininst.py) just appends information (see create_exe) to the stub installers (wininst-9.0.exe and wininst-9.0-amd64.exe) and found in /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command). Note that I slightly monkey-patch the code to use the correct exe (bug with python2.6+).

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried boundling everything on a actual windows machine? I'm slithgly scared that the whole issue is because the original source is missing a lot of dll's that a windows installer might need and there for the package is not complete.

Comment: There's no source though. bdist_wininst appears to do nothing more than append bytes to an existing EXE

Comment: Do you get this error if you run the installer with an empty path?

Comment: @Chris: Are you referring to %%PATH%%?

Comment: Yes. There might be some stray dll on it. It's been a while since I used Windows, but the last time I had Runtime Errors on my mom's laptop, it was solved by starting the script with an empty path.

Comment: Tried wiping %%PATH%%; unfortunately, same problem.

Comment: Do not post text as a pictire. You can Ctrl-C a Windows message box.

Comment: The error means there's a C-level error in the exe. Without a sample to debug, it's impossible to say anything else. Thus voting to close as imposible to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440355/how-to-debug-a-visual-c-runtime-error

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have to create the executable specifically for the x64?
This is the command you would have to run:

```
python setup.py build --plat-name=win-amd64
```

More information can be found here:

http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html#cross-compiling-on-windows

Comment: I already use this option; it is what controls which template EXE bdist_wininst should use. It has no other effect for packages without extension modules (such as mine).

Comment: how to do that when building a pip dependance?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a Visual C++ Redistributable Package is missing or corrupt, try (re)install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1/2010 Redistributable Package (x64) or any other version.

Comment: My apologies; I wasn't clear in the original question. The installation EXE is build w/ setuptool's bdist_wininst where a correct EXE should already exist.

Comment: Then you have an incorrect dependency when you are building the installation exe (maybe somewhere there is an x86-x64 setting or you must map in somekind of config the correct msvcr{version[80/100]}/msvcp[80/100]} dll).

Comment: Again, the EXE already exists.. it is distributed as part of distutils. The bdist_wininst command (see main comments) just appends data to it