# I am getting a C++ runtime error while running access vba module. Consistently reproducible

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I have taken 2 sample databases from online - one for a calendar and one for drag and drop functions - and pulled some code together for a result that is ALMOST functioning as I had hoped.

There is a function to build/refresh the calendar, which works perfectly.
The drag and drop functions work perfectly. (The item is updated in the table to reflect the new date.)

When I drag and drop, the calendar doesn't automatically refresh. If I click next month then last month (which call the refresh function with a new date), the changes are reflected as expected.

The problem is when I try to automatically call the refresh function after a drag/drop event. Access crashes every time I call for a refresh in the code after drag/drop, regardless of where I put the call.

The error says:

> Microsoft visual C++ Runtime Library
>
> Runtime Error!
>
> Program: C:...
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
> unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
> information.

I have tried:

- I thought it might be trying to refresh too fast, so I added a pause
  function and had the program wait 10 seconds after dropping before
  refreshing. Still crashed.
- I did a compact and repair on the database.
- I ran /decompile from the command-line on my accdb file.
- I exported the relevant form, tables, query and module to a new accdb
  file.
- I have tried to re-register the libraries checked under references.
  (RegSvr32 "Path to library file") The only one that succeeded was
  vbe7.dll. The "MS access 14.0 object library", "OLE automation", and
  "MS Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object" don't contain a
  DllRegisterServer method, so regsvr32 did not succeed with those. There are no other
  references checked. Still crashes.
- I have tried countless places to insert the call to refreshcalendar()
- I have stepped through the code and verified the exact place that the
  crash happens. It is commented in the code.

Here is a [link to the database](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B091dbVn-ZlnNjZQZ3JTRW9SVXM/edit?usp=sharing).

To reproduce the problem:

Open frmsubCalendar.
There are 2 entries in May 2014 that can be dropped to other days on the calendar. I can then click the prev/next month buttons on the form, and when May reloads, the change has been made. But if I go into mod_drag_drop under the sub dropdetect() and uncomment the lines noted in the comments, the refresh will crash access at the end of the dropdetect() sub.

I cannot figure out how to make the calendar refresh automatically after a drag/drop event without access crapping the bed.

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger?

Comment: I have never used the debugger before. I will google-fu to find out how.
Edit: I assumed you were talking about using a debugger on the system-level (which I am not savvy to)? Or were you talking about stepping through the vba code? Because I have already done that.

Comment: Whoops, now I see it. Nevermind then ;)

Comment: I came across this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440355/how-to-debug-a-visual-c-runtime-error but I don't have visual studio installed, and the dialog box only gives me an OK button and no debug button. I don't think I have the tools to debug at that level. Would GDB serve this purpose? This is new territory for me and I would like to avoid installing erroneous software if it isn't going to help. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, you didn't go through with gdb? How did you go through step by step then?

Comment: I used breakpoints in the Access VBA editor. So would GDB be useful to me for this?

Comment: I guess that you could analyse the values of your variables, so no, I don't think so.

Comment: I can't duplicate this error....

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a bit outdated, but I had a similar issue and didn't see this one being answered, I figured I'd add this answer for posterity. :) I discovered it was caused by a reference to a function by the form name. I had the following call in a module:

lContractCt = Form_Census.lContractCt_f(bIsMembers)

Where lContract is a Long, there is a form named Census and a public function in that form called lContractCt_f.

I moved the function to a module (so the Form_Census reference wasn't necessary any more). And changed the call to:

lContractCt = lContractCt_f(bIsMembers)

This fixed the error. So, I would check if you have any public function references going from a module to a form and move those public functions into a module. I also saw a similar thread with a different form reference, via Forms![Census], for example.